# Get random item from JSON array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, random

I am having trouble getting a random item from the following JSON using

```
$str = file_get_contents("wisdomquotes.txt"); 
$array = json_decode($str, true); //Fine up to here
$rand = $array[array_rand($array)];//Returns entire array instead of a single random item
```

Here is JSON:

```
{
    "quotes": [{
        "keywords": ["work"],
        "quote": " A stich in time saves nine"
    }, {
        "keywords": ["health"],
        "quote": " An apple a day keeps the doctor away."
    }, {
        "keywords": ["money"],
        "quote": " A penny save is a penny earned."
    }, {
        "keywords": ["work"],
        "quote": " You can't burn the candle at both ends."
    }, {
        "keywords": [""],
        "quote": "Tis better to light a candle than to curse the darkness"
    }]
}
```

What is the correct code to get a random item?

Comment: https://paiza.io/projects/jS0rNqnOMbeP0VcB9wP8rw?language=php | You can do like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the main array in your case is inside the `quotes` sub-array.

```
$rand = $array['quotes'][\array_rand($array['quotes'])];
```

Comment: Awesome.  Got it to work without \

Comment: Which PHP version are you running? Using the global namespace explicitly is quicker (produces less opcodes). Always use the backslash before any global function.

Comment: DIdn't know about that.  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$str = file_get_contents("wisdomquotes.txt"); 
$array = json_decode($str, true);
$rand = array_rand($array['quotes'], 1);
var_dump($array['quotes'][$rand]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might target `$array['quotes']`

```
array_rand($array['quotes'], 1);
```